# Coding conditional expectation in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question about coding out conditional expectation formula as follows,

> E(W|Y)

assuming that E(Y|X) = -1 + 2*X and W = X + N(0,1), X ~ N(1,1).

I have no problem coding out variables as X, W and Y but don't know how to code out E(W|Y) in R.

```
X <- rnorm(100, 1, 1)
W <- X + rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Y <- -1 + 2*X + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1)
```

Then, how should I code out E(W|Y) after that?...

Comment: Why do you have `+ rnorm(100,0,0.1)` in the Y definition?

Comment: The conditional expectation is only one aspect of the distribution.  It's not enough to specify the joint distribution of W and Y, and you need that to get E(W|Y).

Comment: Adding + rnorm(100,0,0.1) is to add a random noise. It's typical way to generate Y

Comment: The joint distribution of W and Y is not available..